# Is it possible to mimic polymorphism using concepts with c++20?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++20, c++-concepts

The question is pretty much given in the titel. [Please considere the following godbolted code:](https://godbolt.org/z/sdEv1x)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base{};
struct Derived : Base{};

template<typename T>
concept IsDerivedFromBase = std::same_as<T, Base>;

template<typename T>
concept IsNotDerivedFromBase = not IsDerivedFromBase<T>;

template <IsDerivedFromBase T>
void foo(T bar) {std::cout << "IsBase" << std::endl;}

template <IsNotDerivedFromBase T>
void foo(T bar) {std::cout << "IsNotBase" << std::endl;}

int main()
{
    Base a;
    foo(a);

    Derived b;
    foo(b);

    Base* c = new Derived{};
    foo(*c);
    delete c;
}
```

The output of the above code reads:

```
IsBase
IsNotBase
IsBase
```

I am asking if it is possible to modify the concepts somehow in order to mimic polymorphism.
The output should read:

```
IsBase
IsNotBase
IsNotBase
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything concept-related is determined and "worked out" at compile time. Setting aside SFINAE for the moment: a failed concept requirement results in an ill-formed program and a compilation failure.

On the other hand, the only part of C++ that could possibly "know" that your `c` does not "really" point to `Base` is `dynamic_cast`, which gets evaluated at ***runtime***. As far as everything else in C++ goes, your `c` points to a `Base` instance, and that's the end of that discussion.

So, to summarize, as far as everything here that gets evaluated at compile time is concerned, your `c` points to a `Base` and there's nothing else that concepts can work with, that will indicate anything else.

Comment: Thank you very much for your argument: (compile time) <-> (runtime). Is it possible to overcome this argument by using dynamic_cast inside a concept?

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is constexpr in C++20, so if you keep your operations in compile time land it should work without any concepts.

Comment: I did find the proposal to make `dynamic_cast` a constexpr, however cppreference.com [makes no mention of this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Comment: Don't know how cppreference deals with constexpr (maybe [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) page?) but if you look at the [draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5.25), you can see that the proposal made it.